# Abrir HTML com link usando NSAttributedString

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iphone

Eu recebo do servidor um HTML similar a esse:

```
"<br>Dummy text<br>Click <a href="www.google.com">Here</a>"
```

No Click Here deveria ser possível clicar e abrir no Safari. Eu tentei implementar o seguinte código: (sendo textMsg um TextView).

```
 NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[[self.myServer textHTML] dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
[self.textMsg setEditable:NO];
[self.textMsg setScrollEnabled:NO];
[self.textMsg setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeLink];
self.textMsg.attributedText = attrStr ;
```

Tentei também de outras formas similares, mas nenhuma funcionou..

No android existe uma função similar, Html.fromHtml().

Recebendo o link dessa forma, haveria uma maneira de fazer com que ele redirecionasse pro browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A url não é aberta automaticamente no browser porque não é indicado o protocolo. Caso você inclua o protocolo, o link sera aberto no Safari:

```
@"<br>Dummy text<br>Click <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Here</a>"
```

Caso queira maior controle sobre a ação ao clicar no link, implemente o método `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)url inRange:(NSRange)characterRange` do delegate de `UITextView`